# RegEx search and replace in Eclipse over multiple lines with start and middle and end

Tags: regex, eclipse

I am struggling to come up with a good regex search and replace for the following case.
I am doing a migration from RichFaces 3 to RichFaces 4 and so far I was able to do a lot of changes with regex.

I've got something like this:

```
     <a:ajax execute="@this"
    rendered="whatever" action="#{bean.method} 
someotherstuff="whatever"
    />
```

What I want to do is to replace the action= with listener= in the above but without changing anything else and I only want to do it within the a:ajax tag. The order and occurrence of the attributes can vary.

So I basically need a search and replace like this:

```
<a:ajax(SEARCH1)action="(.+?)"(SEARCH2)/>
```

replace with

```
<a:ajax$1listener="$2"$3/>
```

Any ideas. I think I might need lookahead but I haven't worked with that yet

Update: The accepted solution does work in Eclipse for searching however there is a known bug in Eclipse that the replace isn't working when you use look around: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=109481

Comment: What's wrong with `(?s)<a:ajax(.+?)action="(.+?)"(.+?)/>` ? (forgot the `s` modifier :)

Comment: Just wanted to clarify - your question is only about the regex expressions and not how to do a replace with those expressions?

Comment: @HamZa At least one thing - `<a:ajax> abcaction="stuff" <a:ajax ... />`. Though I have no idea whether something like this can happen with the given data. `[^>]` instead of `.` might be a better idea.

Comment: @Dukeling Well yeah, it depends on the input ...

Comment: Hi HamZa, the query is a good start but it seems to be a little bit too 'greedy'. It ends on the next /> but not the one from the a:ajax. Another problem would be if you have an <a:ajax .../> without the action= . It would start with that <a:ajax and take everything until it finds action= which might well be in a different tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to replace `action=` with `listener=` inside an a:ajax tag you will need lookbehind instead of lookahead. and you must note that lookbehind in java means you must define the maximum length of the lookbehind range.

Something like `(?<=a:ajax[\w\W\n]{1,100})action="`  with the range of wildcards between 1 until 100, you can increase it if you want by changing the `{1,100}`.

You can do

`.replaceAll("(?<=a:ajax[\\w\\W\\n]{1,100})action=\"","listener=\"")`

Note about regex lookbehind:

- Java allowing finite repetition. You still cannot use the star or
  plus, but you can use the question mark and the curly braces with the
  max parameter specified.
- JGsoft engine and the .NET framework RegEx classes, can do full regex
  inside lookbehind.
- Javascript not supported lookbehind.
- Python can use fixed length only inside lookbehind.

Comment: FYI Most regex engines can't handle that: you must specify a *fixed* length in your lookbehind. The only language capable of doing that out of my head is .NET

Comment: no, java is capable with range, when .net capable of unlimited lookbehind `+ and *`. and I think he said eclipse, thats why I think he use java regex engine.

Comment: Nice one, there is however the danger that if you increase the look behind range too much you might get false positives. I have changed the search to (?<=a:ajax([^<]{0,300}))action as the a:ajax cannot contain another tag. Now I can find all the occurrences with Eclipse however for some strange reasons Eclipse refuses to replace it with anything - but I guess you can't get everything ;-)